# CSS drop-shadow on hover not removing completely on mouse out using Chrome

Tags: html, css, hover, drop-shadow

I have a drop-shadow effect on hover in some transparent png's on my site, but the shadow is not removing completely when the mouse leaves the image (and also is not working at all in Safari and Firefox but that will be another question)

This is the original image:

[image: original image]

This is the image with the drop-shadow:

[image: image with shadow]

And this is the image after mouse leaves:

[image]

Here is the code: and a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqavcnLb/)

CSS:

```
<style>
    img:hover {
       -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222); 
       filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);  
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Triple-Spiral-4turns_green_transparent.png" width="150"/>
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/jqavcnLb/1/

adding a white shadow on normal state will fix it

```
img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
}
img {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #ffffff);
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #ffffff);
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct and will be assisted by two more additions; namely, add padding to the image that is larger that the drop shadow to keep the rendered shadow from getting cut off.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this messes up your layout, but try adding padding:

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Triple-Spiral-4turns_green_transparent.png" width="150" style="padding:10px"/>
```

Comment: As for Safari & Firefox, here is a compatibility chart: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter?#Browser_compatibility. Compatible with Safari 6+ and FF 35+. The JSFiddle works in my Safari 7, but not my FF 31.